# GWT showing blank page.

Tags: gwt

my GWT app is designed to be multipage. And separated into modules. So far all other modules works, except for my 'login' module.

I don't understand why when I access `http://127.0.0.1:8888/login.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` I get a blank page.

LoginEntryPoint:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    GWT.log("Loading module");
     if (!Window.Location.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith("login.html")) { 
         return;
     }
     RootPanel.get().add(new Button("Test"));
}
```

And in the `login.html` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="login/login.nocache.js"></script>
```

and finally in the Login.gwt.xml:

```
<entry-point class='com.mygwtapp.client.LoginEntryPoint' />
```

How to fix this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your log statement happen? If not, is the login.cache.js file even loading (use firebug or the like to check)? If so, can you set a breakpoint on that log statement and step forward, see where it gets to?

And is there anything shown when you run in web mode?

If the login.nocache.js isn't loading, make sure you added `rename-to="login"` in the module tag, make sure it is actually being compiled, etc

Comment: When compiled its still blank.

Comment: When running in debug mode, the log does not happen.

Comment: Then the module isn't running - if it has the entrypoint and the log doesn't run, the module didnt get run. Did you check firebug for errors? were there any errors or log messages in the dev mode console?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure also when you compile the project Remember to add the new module to be compiled

```
Right Click on the Project >> Google >> Gwt Compile >> Add (add your new module)
```

Comment: No you didn't get my point I faced same Problem but every Time I just harry to press compile and forget to customize which modules I want to compile So I mention it beside first answer in case of any one make my mistake ..... don't thank me, thank you for the question :)

Comment: @YouYou you're trully an unsung hero

Answer (score 0):

This problem was happening to me, and I figured out that it was all because I had Buttons in a FormPanel. As soon as I removed them from the FormPanel everything showed up again. I am not sure where exactly you were sticking the button up there, but you might want to try removing the button out of the equation, trying another type of panel and some text, and see if it shows up without the button present.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in hosted mode, this if `if (!Window.Location.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith("login.html")) {` is true, so no button should appear. Try changing the "endsWith" by "contains" method